# How can I display only month, day and year for time section(example Jun 13, 2020)

Tags: javascript, html, arraylist

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NYT API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\nyt.css">
    <script defer src="js\nyt.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Top New York Times HeadLines</h1>
            <h3>This is CTEC 126 Weekly Assignment</h3>
            <label for="section">Select a Section</label>
            <select name="section" id="section">
                <option value="home">Home</option>
                <option value="arts">Art</option>
                <option value="business">Business</option>
                <option value="dining">Dining</option>
                <option value="fashion">Fashion</option>
                <option value="health">Health Magazine</option>
                <option value="nationaloption">National Option</option>
                <option value="politics">Politics</option>
                <option value="realestate">Real Estate</option>
                <option value="science">Science</option>
                <option value="sports">Sports</option>
                <option value="technology">Technology</option>
                <option value="world">World</option>
            </select>
            <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
        </header>
        <div id="stories"></div>
    </section>
    <script>
        const stories = document.querySelector('#stories');

        function callAPI() {
            fetch(`http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section.value}.json?api-key=ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    let output = ''
                    console.log(data);
                    // Call the displayStories() function here to display the content on the page.
                    displayStories(data, output);
                });
        }
        //modify the function to accept one more argument: output
        function displayStories(data, output) {
            data.results.forEach(item => {
                // Adding string for more clarity.
                output += `<div class="hourly">`
                output += `<h1>${(item.title)}</h1>`
                output += `<h1><img style="float: left; width: 120px;" src=${item.multimedia[4].url} alt="ICON"></h1>`
                output += `<div>${(item.created_date)}</div>`
                output += `<div>${(item.byline)}</div>`
                output += `<div> Section: ${(item.section)}</div>`
                output += `<br>`
                output += `<div>${(item.abstract)}</div>`
                output += `</div>`
                stories.style.display = "block"
                stories.innerHTML = output
            });
        }
        const section = document.querySelector('#section')
        const refreshBtn = document.querySelector('#refresh')
        section.addEventListener('change', () => {
            callAPI()
        });
        refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('Refreshing')
            callAPI()
        });
        callAPI();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code, I just want to display Month, day, and year! My code right now will display like this 2020-06-13T13:07:15-04:00, I just want the code display Jun 13,2020 without time or anything behind that! I appreciate any help from you guys! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Date class.

It has built in functions such as getFullYear and others.

```js
let x = new Date();
console.log(x.getFullYear(), x.getDate(), x.getHours(), x.getMinutes(), x.getSeconds());
```

Comment: I can't use this

Comment: Why can't you use it? You can just combine the different times that I've shown above.